# Duplicate Visualisation in Power BI, Same Measures and Column Headings, Different Data Source and Values

Tags: powerbi, measure

I have created a visualisation (table) with many different measures in Power BI, is there now a way to duplicate this visualisation but use a different data source with the same column headings (different values) where the measures and all are also duplicated?

Each measure serves to calculate a column in the visual:

[image]

For example, one of the measures that I created is this:

`No of Sites = COUNT('All Sites TP1'[Facility Country])` Where 'All Sites TP1 is the first data source.

Another measure is as so:

`Performing Sites = CALCULATE(  'All Sites TP1'[No of Sites], OR( 'All Sites TP1'[Site Status]="Completed", 'All Sites TP1'[Site Status]="Ongoing" ) )`

The other calculated measures exist for the columns which are not blacked out, taking a similar form to the ones above.

I now want the exact same visualisation with measures to be created on a different tab of the dashboard, but for my second data source 'All Sites KN' (which contains identical column headings).

I want both of these visualisations to exist simultaneously on the same report. I could replicate every single calculated measure and simply change the data source - but this seems quite long winded and I wanted to enquire and see if there may be a workaround.

Thank you in advance, any assistance and insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a quick way to do what you are after. **However**, I would recommend you append both tables together in PowerQuery, with a Custom Column to distinguish between the two. Once that is done, you can use the same measures and duplicate the visual, then set a visual filter on the Custom Column for each.

**Steps**

1. In Report view, right-click on table `All Sites TP1` and rename it to `All Sites`.
2. In PowerQuery (via `Transform data` in the home tab in the ribbon), find the `All Sites` query, and add a Custom Column. Call it `Source` with a formula of `= "TP1"`.
   [image]
3. In PowerQuery, find the `All Sites KN` query, and add a Custom Column. Call it `Source` with a formula of `= "KN"`.
4. Optional - In PowerQuery, right-click on the `All Sites KN` query, and deselect `Enable load`. This will remove this table from Report view (you won't need it).
5. In PowerQuery, go back to the `All Sites` query. Select `Append Queries` in the Home tab in the ribbon. In the pop-up box, select `All Sites KN` in the drop down and click OK.
6. Click `Close & Apply` in the Home tab in the ribbon, to load the changes and to get back to Report view.

The above steps have appended both tables into one, with column `Source` distinguishing between the two.

Select your Table visual in your report, and in the Filters pane on the right, add `'All Sites'[Source]` column to `Filters on this visual`, and set it to `is TP1`.
[image]

Finally, copy this visual, paste it on a new page, and set the visual filter to `KN`.

Comment: Yes please may I have some more information on how to do this? Will appending the two tables affect my current visualisation? As I want one visual per data source on separate tabs in the dashboard.

Comment: Updated answer above with steps.